# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/ReadSupport - error while reading data from datalake to spark

Tags: azure, apache-spark, neo4j, databricks

I have created a new databricks cluster with the following libraries installed.
Cluster version - 7.6 (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, Scala 2.12)

spark_cdm_connector_0_19_1.jar ,
neo4j_connector_apache_spark_2_12_4_0_1_for_spark_3.jar ,
com.microsoft.azure:spark-cdm-connector:0.19.1 - maven file ,
neo4j-contrib:neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12:4.0.1_for_spark_3 - maven file ,

But while loaing CDM data from datalake to databricks I'm facing the subjected error
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/sources/v2/ReadSupport

Should I need to change the configuration of databricks cluster or update the configuration file?
Thanks

Comment: most probably the `spark_cdm_connector_0_19_1` is compiled for Spark 2.4

Comment: Check the scala version on which the the jars are compiled, My guess is a jar is compiled on 2.11 version whereas you Cluster has 2.12 scala version. You have to use jar for 2.12 versions.